# Kmz files For Google Map Javascript

Tags: google-maps, kmz

I want to upload **KMZ files** from my local drive to google map , till  now I haven't find any method to upload a local **KMZ file** to google map, 
the approach is valid for a KMZ file that is publicly hosted how can I upload file from Local Path/source

**app.js**

```
  <html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Click Capture Sample</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 370px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 360px;
            width: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left;
            border: thin solid #333;
        }
        #capture {
            height: 360px;
            width: 480px;
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left;
            background-color: #ECECFB;
            border: thin solid #333;
            border-left: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="capture"></div>
<script>
    var map;
     var src = 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/assets/mdata.kmz';

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
            zoom: 2,
            mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            preserveViewport: false,
            map: map
        });
        kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
            var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
            var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
            testimonial.innerHTML = content;
        });
    }
</script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="21312312312312313123..."&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using a file:/// url

Comment: @neuhaus how can I upload Kmz file then

Comment: [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/) has information about file urls in Windows

Comment: i have correct url for the path but its not parsing it

Comment: What's in the browser console? It's probably a permissions issue then.

Comment: the status is :

Comment: ƒ ()
status
:
"INVALID_REQUEST"
suppressInfoWindows
:
true
url
:
"localhost3000/public/example.kmz"

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid file:/// URL! Anyway.. I'm sorry I can't help you, I don't use Windows.

Comment: tell me how u upload a KMl file i will find alternative for that

Comment: You can't use KmlLayer with local files, KmlLayer requires publicly available files/URLs. There are third party parsers that support local KMZ files.